# R foreach data return

Tags: r

suppose I have groups of experimental and control data and want to take the standard deviation of each group and return two lists of results, the following code works

```
experimental <- replicate(3,rnorm(10))
control      <- replicate(3,rnorm(10))

# experimental and control data look like
#             [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
# [1,] -1.98749717 -1.37039284 -2.1681745
# [2,]  0.51401787  0.22997560  1.3334176
# ...ten rows total

rcomb  <- function(...) { mapply('rbind',...,SIMPLIFY=FALSE) } #for combining results

result <- foreach(i=iter(experimental,by='row'),j=iter(control,by='row'),
               .combine='rcomb',.multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {

                c(sd(i),sd(j))

                }

result[[1]] #experimental results (what I want)

#           [,1]
# [1,] 0.9527986
# [2,] 0.3180453
# [3,] 0.8088746
# ...ten rows total; likewise for the control; what I want
```

in reality I am selecting the data from an sql query that uses group concat and can't get the results to return the way I want. I must be overlooking something simple.

```
data <- dbGetQuery(database_connection, "select group_concat from ...

# data looks like
#
#    experimental  control
# 1      14,14,14 14,14,14
# 2      15,15,15 15,15,15
# 3         9,9,9    9,9,9
#
# ...many rows

attach(data)

result <- foreach(i=iter(data$experimental,by="row"),j=iter(data$control,by="row",
               .combine='rcomb',.multicombine=TRUE)) %dopar% {

                c(sd(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(i,',')))),
                  sd(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(j,',')))))

                }

result[[1]] # instead of what I want it only gives the first pair

# [1] 0 0
```

Although Im new to R I've looked at all the data types closely, what am I missing?

Comment: Superfluous side note: Never (ever) use `attach`. Toss it in the garbage. To accomplish the same thing, take a look at `with`.

Comment: First: I concur with not using attach(), ever! Second: build a working example with the data in the form that you get from the data base.